# What's the difference between super and this in Dart while overriding an operator?

Tags: dart

**Minimal reproducible code:**

```dart
void main() {
  const one = Foo();
  const two = Foo();
  print(one == two);
}

class Foo {
  const Foo();

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) {
    assert(super == this); // Works (Line - 1)
    return this == other; // Error (Line - 2)
    // return super == other; // Works 
  }
}
```

The assertion works `(Line - 1)`, but `(Line - 2)` fails with the following error. However, `return super == other` works too.

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceededError: RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: Hoped this help: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dart-super-and-this-keyword/

Comment: Thanks for the link, but unfortunately it didn't help :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, line 1 works because you are using the == operator from the `Object` class which determines equality based on the address of the object.

On line 2 you are getting a stack overflow (the error, not this website) because when you test for equality the `==` operator will be called, but when execution reaches "Line - 2", you are again calling the `==` operator causing a recursive call back to the `==` method. This causes an unbounded loop of filling up your call stack with calls to `==` until it overflows causing the error you are getting.

There is no special meaning to `super` or `this` when overloading an operator. Their meanings remain the same as always. `this` refers to the current object. `super` refers to the parent object. (remember that all objects have an implied super-class of `Object` if none is specified.

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer but even if I use `return other == this`, that also causes stack overflow error. In this case, I'm invoking `==` operator from Object class.

Comment: How are you determining that you are invoking `==` from the Object class? `other` is still an instance of `foo`

Comment: I don't think `other` is an instance of `Foo` because it's declared as `Object other`

Comment: While the argument to the `==` operator method is `Object`, your `other` object is of type `Foo` and the `Foo` implementation of `==` will be called. This is how polymorphism works.

Comment: If this is how things work, then why do they check for `return other is Foo && ...;` when overriding an operator `==`?

Comment: Presumably because "they" are wanting to check that the object type passed to `==` is of type `Foo` before going on to check other things. It would depend on who "they" is and how they were wanting to determine equality. `other == 5` is valid dart. It will always be false, but it is valid. However if `Foo` had a member `String name` I may want to check that the name is equal in both instances. `5.name` however does not exist and would be an error.

Comment: "they" are the Google developers. So, according to you, should this not be a compile error to use `==` on `Foo` class like inside a `main` method `var f = Foo();` `Object o = 1`. `if (f == o) ...`

Comment: That is correct. If you try it you will not get an error. Again, the if statement will always evaluate to false, but it is not an error. Please do some further reading on the subject. This has turned from me answering your question, to me becoming your tutor. Best of luck with it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion but I think you need to do some studies before answering the question which you're not very sure of, like `other` is already `Foo`. Best of luck with your study.

Comment: @iDecode What Stephen wrote is correct.   There is no guarantee that `other` has the same type as `this`, so `operator ==` implementations typically check `other is Foo`. `foo == bar` calls `foo`'s `operator ==`, but `bar == foo` calls `bar`'s `operator ==`.  `foo` and `bar` could be different types.  The only thing that `operator ==` knows is that `other` is not null.

Comment: @jamesdlin It wasn't Stephen who wrote that, but me. Stephen said that `other` is of type `Foo` but I said it is of type `Object`, so sir which type `other` is?

Comment: @iDecode You were asking why existing code checks the type of `other`.  Stephen was explaining that you won't get any compilation errors if code tries using `==` on different types.

Comment: @jamesdlin Sir, can you read the 2nd comment of him;  "other is still an instance of foo", is that correct?

Comment: I think Stephen meant that *in your example*, `other` is an instance of `Foo` at runtime.  That's not known at compilation time nor true in general.  In your example, `other == this` will invoke `operator ==` on `other`, which due to virtual dispatch will still invoke `Foo.operator ==`.

Comment: @jamesdlin When I'm doing `super == this`, it invokes `==` operator on `Object` class, right?

Comment: Yes, it would invoke the `operator ==` implementation from the superclass (which in this case would be `Object` and compare object identity).

Comment: @jamesdlin Your comment is the reason why I was able to understand this post :) But sir I can't `print(super)`. Should I ask this as a separate question?

Comment: Yes, that's a different question.